# Asp.net mvc 5 change mvc application culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i used that great blog of afana about ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization.
[Here is the link](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)

but i have strange bug when i try to post then use

```
 return RedirectToRoute("order-es");
```

this should go to "/es/orderes" but it goes to "/en/order" change to current culture from spanish to english (defualt)

sorry for my bad english and thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line 16 of the HomeController. Make sure the returned value is "es".

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config file try adding this line in `<system.web>` for setting the culture

```
<system.web>


     <globalization culture="en-US" />


<system.web>
```